# Why does google.com page has six input element in the HTML source?

Tags: html, google-search

I was just inspecting the source HTML for `www.google.com` and I found out that they have multiple `<input>` fields. I am just curious that if anyone can tell my why do they do it?

Comment: There are 6 input fields.

Comment: Right, I just saw that. :)

Answer (score -1):

Might contain certain server generated codes. Most of those input are hidden.